# Unable to retrieve a cookie set by another application on the same domain

Tags: security, session, cookies, request

We have a Laravel app that sets a cookie:

```
public function make($name, $value, $minutes = 0, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = false, $httpOnly = true)
{
    list($path, $domain) = $this->getPathAndDomain($path, $domain);

    $time = ($minutes == 0) ? 0 : time() + ($minutes * 60);

    return new Cookie($name, $value, $time, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
}
```

The values passed are as follows:

```
array (size=7)
    0 => string 'imph_auth' (length=9)
    1 => string 'Russ Back' (length=9)
    2 => int 2628000
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => boolean false
    6 => boolean true
```

I've tried to retrieve that cookie in a Craft template as follows:

```
craft.request.getCookie('imph_auth')
```

However I get null when I know that it's been set (I can browse to a Laravel template on the same domain and get the cookie).

I note the JavaScript warning in the Craft docs but this is set in PHP, however I can see the **getCookies()** method of the **CookieCollection** class runs each cookie through **craft()->security->validateData()** and fails validation.

Is there any way I can get around this without resorting to my own PHP in the template or a custom plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can get around this without resorting to my own PHP in the template or a custom plugin?

You can't have PHP is a Twig template, but I think you'd need a real simple plugin for this.

It would just have an `init()` method that did:

```
craft()->request->enableCookieValidation = false;
```

Just be aware that's going to make it much easier for people to potentially tamper with cookie values.

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I opted instead for a simple plugin with a Twig extension that lets me get a cookie for a specific key, so everything else remains secure.

Comment: @RussBack could you mention the name of the plugin you're using?